# Apple App Store StoreKit 2 • What is subscriptionGroupID in status(for groupID: String)?

Tags: ios, storekit

I want to access the latest transaction for a Subscription Group. I use the following method [`static func status(for groupID: String) async throws -> \[Product.SubscriptionInfo.Status\]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/subscriptioninfo/3822297-status) to access the statuses for the group, and from there, I can get a verified transaction from the status.

But when I set the GroupID equal to the Subscription Group Reference Name I put in the .storekit configuration file in Xcode, I don't have any status (so wrong ID). Actually, I have to use a subscriptionGroupID like 3F19ED53 (found using a previous transaction: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3749718-subscriptiongroupid).

When I look into a Product, this ID is set for subscriptionFamilyId.
So my question is how can I know the ID if it's not the one I provided in App Store Connect or the config file? Do I first have to access a Product from this group?
Thanks.